# update/modify to add element in array(with same key) in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this in a mongoDB collection "users"-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769bdb97689b3d7c91b0fcc"),
    "id" : 1234,
    "address" : [
            "address1",
            "address2"
                ]
}
```

I want to add an address in the array using "id" and make it of the form-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769bdb97689b3d7c91b0fcc"),
    "id" : 1234,
    "address" : [
            "address1",
            "address2",
            "address3"
                ]
}
```

I am using this statement-

```
db.users.update({ "id": 1234 },{ $set: { "address": "address3" }});
```

but it replaces both the existing addresses and makes it of the form-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5769bdb97689b3d7c91b0fcc"),
    "id" : 1234,
    "address" : [
            "address3"
                ]
}
```

I don't have an easy access to the previously stored addresses.
Any suggestions how to go about it?
Any alternative way of storage is also welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the $push modifier: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

```
db.users.update({ "id": 1234 },{ $push: { "address": "address3" }});
```